# DSP performance, what should be avoided?

Tags: c++, performance, signal-processing

I am starting with dsp programming right now and am writing my first low level classes and functions. 
Since I want the functions to be fast (or at last not inefficient), I often wonder what I should use and what I should avoid in functions which get called per sample.

I know that the speed of an instruction varies quite a bit but I think that some of you at least can share a rule of thumb or just experience. :)

**conditional statements**

If I have to use conditions, `switch` should be faster than an `if / else if` block, right?
Are there differences between using two `if`-statements or an `if-else`? Somewhere I read that `else` should be avoided but I don't know why.

Also, compared to a multiplication, is there a rude estimation how much more time an if-block takes? Because in some cases, using multiplications by zero could be used instead of if-statements:

```cpp
//something could be an int either 1 or 0:
if(something) {
    signal += something_else;
}
// or:
signa+ += something*something_else;
```

**functions and function-pointers**

Instead of using conditional statements, you could use function-pointer. Instead of using conditions in every call, the pointer could be redirected to a specific function. However, for every call, the pointer had to be interpreted in order to call the right function. So I don't know if this would help or not.

What I also wonder is if calling functions have an impact. If so, boxing functions should be avoided, right?

**variables**

I would think that defining and using many variables in a function doesn't realy have an impact, at least relative to calculations. Is this true? If not, reusing declared variables would be better than more declaration.

**calculations**
Is there an order of calculation-types in term of the time they take to execute? I am sure that this highly depends on the context but a rule of thumb would be nice. I often read that people only count the multiplication in an algorithm. Is this because additions are realtively fast?
Does it make a difference between multiplication and division? (`*0.5` or `/2.0`)

I hope that you can share soem experience.

Cheers

Comment: Implement first, optimize second.  That is, don't worry about performance until you have working code.  Then profile your working code and optimize the bottlenecks.

Comment: Nowadays with complex optimizing compilers the only real way to answer this question is by telling you to profile. A compiler usually 'knows' to convert a floating point division to a multiplication if it can and with branch prediction etc. on modern CPUs it is difficult to answer your question in a general, useful way.

Comment: Like I said, I won't start squeezing the nanoseconds out of my algorithm but for designing classes and functions, some basic rules would realy help. :)

Comment: I have an example here if you wonder why I am asking this:

I have a biquad-function which does the basic biquad-computation. I maybe wan't to change the filter to cut off with 24db/octave instead of 12db/octave. So in the biquad-function, I would make a condition and if the 24db-bool is set, the sample gets filtered by another biquad-instance.

Would this `if`-statement have an impact or is it "cheap" compared to the generall biquad-computation (five multiplications, some additions and assignments)

Comment: You might also consider using an existing library or framework rather than reinventing everything (unless the purpose is just to learn). A comparison can be found [here](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~nils/exchange/cnmat/RobinsonBullock2012.pdf)

Comment: what kind of machine is this for? even on a low end mobile phone, a single biquad calculated in realtime at 44100 is unlikely to hurt performance.

Comment: No specific machine but PC's and mobile devices like android and iOS. 

@Jamie Bullock, the purpos is exactly this. :) I try to develop a synthesis libary for audio synthesis.

Answer (score 2):

here are part of the answers:

calculations (talking about native precision of the processor for example 32bits):

- Most DSP microprocessors have single cycle multipliers,  that means a
  multiply costs exactly the same as an addition in term of cycles.
- and multiplication it generally faster then division.

conditional statements:

if/else - when looking in the assembly code you can see that the memory of the if condition is usually loaded by default, so when using if else make sure that the condition that will happen more frequently will be in the if.

but generally if possible you should avoid if/else in a loop to improve the pipe lining.

good luck.

Comment: Hi, 
do these notes also hold for normal x86/x64 CPUs? I am developing for windows, totaly forgott that DSP refers to "processor" and "processing". :/

Comment: This notes refer specifically do DSPs

Answer (score 1):

DSP compilers are typically good at optimizing `for` loops that **do not** contain function-calls.

Therefore, try to inline every function that you call from within a time-critical `for` loop.

If your DSP is a fixed-point processor, then floating-point operations are implemented by SW.

This means that every such operation is essentially replaced by the compiler with a library function.

So you should basically avoid performing floating-point operations inside time-critical `for` loops.

The preprocessor should provide a special `#pragma` for the number of iterations of a `for` loop:

- Minimum number of iterations
- Maximum number of iterations
- Multiplicity of the number of iterations

Use this `#pragma` where possible, in order to help the compiler to perform loop-unrolling where possible.

Finally, DSPs usually support a set of unique operations for enhanced performance.

As an example, consider `_dotpu4` on [Texas Instruments C64xx](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spru187v/spru187v.pdf), which computes the scalar-product of two integers `src1` and `src2`: For each pair of 8-bit values in `src1` and `src2`, the 8-bit value from `src1` is multiplied with the 8-bit value from `src2`, and the four products are summed together.

Check the data-sheet of your DSP, and see if you can make use of any of these operations.

The compiler should generate an intermediate file, which you can explore in order to analyze the expected performance of each of the optimized `for` loops in your code.

Based on that, you can try different assembly operations that might yield better results.

Comment: Yay! another C64xx programmer on stackoverflow.

Comment: @NilsPipenbrinck: Haha, nice to make your acquaintance :) I thought I was the only one left (though indeed I gotta admit that last time I used it was somewhere around 2005).